# Mybatis foreach iteration over list of integers within a complex object parameter

Tags: java, playframework, mybatis

I am using MyBatis 3.2.8 in a Play Framework 2.3.6 Java project. I've been struggling for several days with iterating over a list of integers that is passed to a MyBatis mapper within a complex object parameter. Here is my setup:

I have a class called EventFilter in EventFilter.java:

```
public class EventFilter {
private String beginDate;
private String endDate;
private List<Integer> closestCountry;
private List<Integer> territorialWaterStatus;
private List<Integer> vesselCountry;
private String closestCountryInClause;
private String territorialWaterStatusInClause;
private String vesselCountryInClause;

public EventFilter() { }

public EventFilter(JsonNode jsonNode){
    this.beginDate = jsonNode.get("beginDate").asText();
    this.endDate = jsonNode.get("endDate").asText();
    this.closestCountry = JsonHelper.arrayNodeToIntegerList((ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("closestCountry"));
    this.territorialWaterStatus = JsonHelper.arrayNodeToIntegerList((ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("territorialWaterStatus"));
    this.vesselCountry = JsonHelper.arrayNodeToIntegerList((ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("vesselCountry"));
}

public String getBeginDate() {
    return beginDate;
}

public void setBeginDate(String beginDate) {
    this.beginDate = beginDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public List<Integer> getTerritorialWaterStatus() {
    if(this.territorialWaterStatus.size() > 0) {
        return territorialWaterStatus;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setTerritorialWaterStatus(List<Integer> territorialWaterStatus) {
    this.territorialWaterStatus = territorialWaterStatus;
}

public List<Integer> getClosestCountry() {
    if(this.closestCountry.size() > 0) {
        return closestCountry;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setClosestCountry(List<Integer> closestCountry) {
    this.closestCountry = closestCountry;
}

public List<Integer> getVesselCountry() {
    if(this.vesselCountry.size() > 0) {
        return vesselCountry;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setVesselCountry(List<Integer> vesselCountry) {
    this.vesselCountry = vesselCountry;
}
```

}

This is referenced as a type alias in my mybatis config file:

```
<configuration>

<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias type="models.Event" alias="Event"/>
    <typeAlias type="models.EventFilter" alias="EventFilter"/>
    <typeAlias type="models.Country" alias="Country"/>
</typeAliases>

<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mpmap"/>
            <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="password" value="dbpw"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>

<mappers>
    <mapper resource="EventMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
</configuration>
```

I have a mapper that takes an EventFilter object as its parameter. It should then check if the beginDate, endDate, closestCountry, vesselCountry, and territorialWaterStatus are set. If they are it uses them for the WHERE clause:

```
<select id="getEventsWithFilter" resultType="Event" resultMap="EventResult">
    SELECT ev.id, to_char(ev.occurred_on, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS occurred_on_date,
        to_char(ev.occurred_on, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS occurred_on_time,
        ST_X(ev.location) AS longitude, ST_Y(ev.location) AS latitude,
        COALESCE(co01.name, 'Unspecified') AS closest_country,
        COALESCE(co02.name, 'Unspecified') AS territorial_water_status,
        COALESCE(co03.name, 'Unspecified') AS vessel_flag_country
    FROM event AS ev
    LEFT JOIN country AS co01
        ON co01.cow_id = ev.location_closest_country_id
    LEFT JOIN country AS co02
        ON co02.cow_id = ev.location_water_status_country_id
    LEFT JOIN country AS co03
        ON co03.cow_id = ev.vessel_flag_country_id
    <where>
        <if test="#{eventFilter.beginDate} != null and #{eventFilter.endDate} != null">
            ev.occurred_on &gt;= #{eventFilter.beginDate}::timestamp AND ev.occurred_on &lt;= #{eventFilter.endDate}::timestamp
        </if>
        <if test="#{eventFilter.closestCountry} != null">
            AND ev.location_closest_country_id IN
            <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="#{eventFilter.closestCountry}" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{id}
            </foreach>
        </if>
        <if test="#{eventFilter.territorialWaterStatus} != null">
            AND ev.location_water_status_country_id IN
            <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="#{eventFilter.territorialWaterStatus}" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{id}
            </foreach>
        </if>
        <if test="#{eventFilter.vesselCountry} != null">
            AND ev.vessel_flag_country_id IN
            <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="#{eventFilter.vesselCountry}" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{id}
            </foreach>
        </if>
    </where>
    ORDER BY ev.occurred_on ASC;
</select>
```

I have the mapper linked into an interface as follows:

```
    public List<Event> getEventsWithFilter(@Param("eventFilter") EventFilter eventFilter);
```

And I am calling it with a MybatisMapper helper class that generates my session as follows:

```
public static List<Event> getEvents(EventFilter eventFilter) {
    MybatisMapper mapper = new MybatisMapper();
    SqlSession session = mapper.getSession();
    EventMapper eventMapper = session.getMapper(EventMapper.class);

    List<Event> events;

    List<Integer> li = eventFilter.getClosestCountry();

    try {
        events = eventMapper.getEventsWithFilter(eventFilter);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return events;
}
```

**The Problem(s):**

The beginDate and endDate work completely fine by themselves. But I'm having the following problems with the integer lists:

1. The if statement checking if the list is null seems to be getting
   ignored, or evaluating to true when it should be false.
2. The integer lists are appearing to be passed as null into the IN clauses.
3. If I comment out the integer list IN clauses, and just to beginDate and
   endDate, it works completely fine. However, if I leave the integer
   list IN clauses, the query doesn't fail, but it returns an empty
   set, as if to say "WHERE column IN ()".

Here is the console logging printed by Play and Mybatis when the mapper/query are executed, along with the EventFilter printing its contents. They're a little lengthy so I put them in pastebin:

- When I pass three countries for each of the three integer lists: http://pastebin.com/aWcXyikh
- When I pass only the beginDate and endDate: http://pastebin.com/CeCv256g

This became a little longer than I wanted it to, but thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Also, here is the debug log when I comment out the last three if statements and iterations in the mapper: http://pastebin.com/6feWzd0D

Comment: I am unable to see your logs because of my firewall restrictions, but could it be that whoever is populating EventFilter (guessing your MVC framework) is not populating it properly because you're using List<Integer> as opposed to array of primitive data type?

Comment: Hmm. Ok, so use an array of ints instead of a list of integers? By all indications the mybatis foreach seems to be list and map friendly, but I'll give that a try.

Comment: What I was suggesting is to ensure that the data is populated before you call myBatis mapper, i.e. in getEvents, just examine if the Integer list is populated first before suspecting myBatis. Again, you may have done this and it shows up in your logs, but I can't see it. If it is there, try using an array of primitive data type of int.

Comment: Aha yes I have done that and the list is populated before the eventfilter object is passed to the mapper. I'll try changing it to a primitive type but I would prefer to keep it as is if possible

Comment: OK, I've tried it with an int[] array. When eventFilter is created the int[] array is initialized and I've set breakpoints to make sure the list is initialized, but then the parameter is still logged as null.

Answer (score 8):

I finally got it working. The only thing I ended up having to change was addressing the parameter lists in my XML mapper without the surrounding curly braces.

So instead of:

```
 <if test="#{eventFilter.closestCountry} != null">
        AND ev.location_closest_country_id IN
        <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="#{eventFilter.closestCountry}" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{id}
        </foreach>
    </if>
```

It should be:

```
<if test="eventFilter.closestCountry != null">
            AND ev.location_closest_country_id IN
            <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="eventFilter.closestCountry" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{id}
            </foreach>
        </if>
```

Which is odd, because addressing strings in the passed object works with either method - i.e. #{eventFilter.beginDate} is the same as eventFilter.beginDate.

A very subtle difference, but I hope it helps someone save some time in the future.

Comment: I suspect that the reason for the lack of {} is that the `collection` attribute may also take values like `array` and `list`, so this is for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<if test="eventFilter.closestCountry != null">
        AND ev.location_closest_country_id IN
        <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="eventFilter.closestCountry" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            ${id}
        </foreach>
    </if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MyBatis v. 3.4.6.

My case:

```
@Mapper
public interface CorsoMapper {
    List<CorsoEntity> elenco(Filtro filtro);
}


public class Filtro implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8357822764110641974L;

    private String codice;
    private List<String> codici;

    public String getCodice() {
        return codice;
    }

    public void setCodice(String codice) {
        this.codice = codice;
    }

    public List<String> getCodici() {
        return codici;
    }

    public void setCodici(List<String> codici) {
        this.codici = codici;
    }
}
```

SQL:

```
<select id="elencoCorsi" parameterType="it.blabla.Filtro" resultMap="corsoMap">
    AND CODICI IN
    <foreach item="c" collection="codici" open="(" separator="," close=")">
       #{c}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

It works without using "index" attribute.