# MyBatis where in Enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, mybatis

I'm using Java spring and MyBatis.
I have an Enum like this

```java
public enum MyEnum {
   A,B,C,D,E
}
```

now I want to write a query and in my query I want to have this :

```
SELECT * FROM table where myColumn in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

How can I achieve this?
I tried converting it to array of strings in my java code and pass it as parameter to my query, and I created this query :

```java
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="#{searchParams.stringValues}" open="AND table.myColumn IN ('" separator="','" close="')">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```

and I receive following error :

```
Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 11, number of columns: 10.\"
```

BTW, I'm using xml files for my queries.
I've checked this answer : [Mybatis foreach iteration over list of integers within a complex object parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641563/mybatis-foreach-iteration-over-list-of-integers-within-a-complex-object-paramete)
which appears to work for list of integers but apparently not for list of strings or enums.

Comment: 1) You cannot use `#{}` in `collection` attribute (i.e. it should be `collection="searchParams.stringValues"`). 2) If you enclose `#{}` with single quotes, the driver treats it as a string literal and does not recognize it as a placeholder. Assuming that the type of `searchParams.stringValues` is `List< MyEnum>` or `MyEnum[]`, it should work if you fixed these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First comment solved my issue, so I should replace this:

```java
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="#{searchParams.stringValues}" open="AND table.myColumn IN ('" separator="','" close="')">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```

with this:

```java
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="searchParams.stringValues" open="AND table.myColumn IN (" separator="," close=")">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```